# Fastest way to store a file to stream from Service Fabric application?

Tags: azure, file, service, microservices, azure-service-fabric

***Scenario:***

I want a service fabric app that can return a file when requested like `[GET] /{fileId}/read`.

Let's say that `fileId` is associated with a `customerId`, e.g.

```
 =======================
   customerId  | fileId
 =======================
       1       |   1
 -----------------------
       1       |   2
 -----------------------
       1       |   3
 -----------------------
       2       |   4
 -----------------------
       2       |   5
```

These are distinct combinations (no 2 `fileId`s for the same `customerId`).

I want `customerId` to be the unit of scale. In other words, the load on `customerId=326` should not affect the performance of `customerId=913842`, but the load on `customerId=326` can affect it's own performance.

I'm not that experienced in understanding stateful services, reliable actors, partinioning, etc.

I'm wondering if I can achieve something where these files would be stored on physical disks of the nodes, for direct access. It would look something like this:

```
     Node0        Node1       Node2     Node3    Node4
        \         /            |          \        /
         Customer1        Customer2        Customer3
```

---

```
                \
                 \
```

---

```
                  |
                  |
                  |
           [GET] /3/stream
```

and the file `3` might be stored directly on `Node1`'s disk at `E:\\files\foo.txt` so it can be streamed fast.

Is this even possible, or what is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend you using the Node Disks as a storage for your services.

First, because nodes with your data can be lost\replaced, and you would need to handle a way to backup and restores these files where the services are running. Also, the Ephemeral Disk in the node might lose the data after a reboot(Something common to happen).

Second, to make your services isolated from each other as you described, you would need to pin a service to a specific node or NodeType using PlacementContraints, this would make the services less reliable, as they will rely on a node being up and if they fail they couldn't be placed in other nodes. Also, You might under utilize the node resources, as you need to allocated the node for the client.

Third, to make them truly isolated, you would have to expose the services direct to the clients, and the clients need to know how to find each service based on their CustomerID, making the client communication coupled to the way you deploy your services in the cluster. If you use a Proxy, you would put the load in the proxy.

These are just a few issues I see on this design.

There are many ways you could handle files, but you didn't let clear why you want to store these files. What I can point you to is:

1. Using Azure Storage to store the files
2. Allocate the node partitions(Customer) dynamically instead of pin them to the nodes
3. Set Resource Limits to the services(Memory & CPU)
4. Use Custom Metrics
5. Add Rate Limits to throttle the usage for each customer

With these directions:

1. you don't have to worry about the management of files, because Azure Storage will manage the replication for you according to the configuration you chose;
2. Dynamically allocated services will make a good use of the resources, so you don't allocate a full node to a service and the node gets under-utilized, wasting resources(money).
3. Restricting the limits of Memory and CPU a service can use will prevent the service of consuming too much resources affecting other services.
4. Using custom metrics you can let the services report the load to Service Fabric; Service Fabric will balance the services to avoid nodes being idle while others are busy. Also can use to Auto Scale the instances of services if they get busy.
5. Adding Rate Limit to the services will prevent users abusing it and making use in a smoother way, preventing sudden usage spike from one customer affecting others.